# How can i change excel sheets with 5sec time gap one after another using VB code by macro?

Tags: excel

I have more than 10 excel sheets in a work book prepared for a seminar .I have to make a slide show for these sheets ,so that each sheet should be automatically changed one after the other.Can u please help me solve this task ?

Comment: You can use OnTime for this.  http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/08/automatically-event-repeat-in-excel-vba.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you get started. It will show each sheet in a workbook every 5 seconds, starting at the first sheet in the workbook and ending with the last.

```
Sub StartSlideShow()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "ShowNextSheet"
End Sub

Sub ShowNextSheet()
    Dim lastIndex As Integer, nextShtIndex As Integer

    lastShtIndex = Worksheets.Count
    nextShtIndex = ActiveSheet.Index + 1

    If nextShtIndex <= lastShtIndex Then
        Worksheets(nextShtIndex).Select
        StartSlideShow
    Else
        MsgBox "End of slide show"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In excel how can i add values from two different sheets and print the result in the third sheet through macro ?

Comment: If you want to add values in `A1` from sheets 1 and 2 and put the result in `Al` in sheet 3 then it would be something like: `Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") + Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")