# Continuous Worksheet Switching Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet to display SQL Data charts that will show on a monitor in our machine shop.

The spreadsheet has 45 tabs and I need to switch between tabs with an interval of 10 seconds per tab and then return to the first tab and repeat the loop.

I found [How can i change excel sheets with 5sec time gap one after another using VB code by macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233753/how-can-i-change-excel-sheets-with-5sec-time-gap-one-after-another-using-vb-code)).

How do I make the code loop indefinitely?

Here's the code from the link:

```vb
Sub StartSlideShow()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "ShowNextSheet"
End Sub

Sub ShowNextSheet()
    Dim lastIndex As Integer, nextShtIndex As Integer

    lastShtIndex = Worksheets.Count
    nextShtIndex = ActiveSheet.Index + 1

    If nextShtIndex &lt;= lastShtIndex Then
        Worksheets(nextShtIndex).Select
        StartSlideShow
    Else
        MsgBox "End of slide show"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the "slideshow" need to run 24 hours a day?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This spreadsheet will be running 24 hours a day.

Comment: Then the answer below will work, just dont forget to change `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "ShowNextSheet"` to `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "ShowNextSheet"` since you want the change to happen every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you're currently using checks if the index of the next sheet is less than (or equal to) the last index of the workbook. If it isn't (meaning you've gone through all of your sheets), then the application terminates. In your case, you don't want to terminate the application, so in the case that the next sheet index is greater than the last sheet, simply select the first sheet manually, and refire the code.

```
If nextShtIndex <= lastShtIndex Then
    Worksheets(nextShtIndex).Select
    StartSlideShow
Else
    Worksheets(1).Select
    StartSlideShow
End If
```

Comment: I've updated the code to look like this: `Sub StartSlideShow()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "ShowNextSheet"
End Sub

Sub ShowNextSheet()
    Dim lastIndex As Integer, nextShtIndex As Integer

    lastShtIndex = Worksheets.Count
    nextShtIndex = ActiveSheet.Index + 1

If nextShtIndex <= lastShtIndex Then
    Worksheets(nextShtIndex).Select
    StartSlideShow
Else
    Worksheets(1).Select
    StartSlideShow
End If
End Sub

`
It posts Runtime Error '1004'
Select method of Worksheet class failed

Says line   `Worksheets(nextShtIndex).Select` is issue

Comment: Found out what was causing the error - A hidden sheet was interrupting the sequence, Unhid the sheet and it started working.

Comment: @dausfaul Great to hear. Hidden sheets can't be selected.