# Excel - Automated Worksheet Switching Loop **only specific worksheets**

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an excel dashboard and need to display 2 specific worksheets in the workbook and switch between tabs with an interval of 30 seconds per tab and then return to the first tab and repeat.

I found a macro that is similar to what I need, [Excel - Automated Worksheet Switching Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55617779/excel-automated-worksheet-switching-loop), however I am trying to only show 2 specific worksheets and not all worksheets in the workbook.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Sub StartSlideShow()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "ShowNextSheet"
End Sub

Sub ShowNextSheet()

    Dim lastIndex As Integer, nextShtIndex As Integer

    lastShtIndex = Worksheets.Count
    nextShtIndex = ActiveSheet.Index + 1

    If nextShtIndex <= lastShtIndex Then
        Worksheets(nextShtIndex).Select
        StartSlideShow
    Else
        Worksheets(1).Select
        StartSlideShow
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Sub SlideToOne()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "ShowFirstSheet"
End Sub

Sub SlideToTwo()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "ShowSecondSheet"
End Sub

Sub ShowFirstSheet()
    Worksheets(1).Select
    SlideToTwo
End Sub

Sub ShowSecondSheet()
    Worksheets(2).Select
    SlideToOne
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there some way to have it automatically start running the macro when the file is open?

Comment: ```Private Sub Workbook_Open()
code here
End Sub```